# 2D Body Transformation and Rotation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, transformation

I defined the following rectangle in Matlab:

```
A = [-4,-4,4,4,-4;-2,2,2,-2,-2;]
```

And I defined a transformation matrix (Special Euclidean (2)) like this:

```
function T = se2(x, y, theta)
T = [cosd(theta), -sind(theta), x;
     sind(theta), cosd(theta), y;
      0,        0,           1];
```

Now, I want to rotate my shape by 45 degrees counter-clockwise about its center  and move it with respect to the **new coordinate frame** by 2 unit in the **new** y direction.

**First problem is**: when doing like the following:...

```
B = se2(0,2,45)*[A;1 1 1 1 1]
```

...it will correctly rotate but incorrectly move my shape.
Here is my rectangle(blue), incorrect transformation(red) and correct transformation(green):
[image: The image]

**Second problem is:** Suppose I translated the shape by 6 direction in the y direction. I want to just rotate the rectangle by -30 degrees about it's **new center** but doing as I've shown, yields rotation about the former center.
[image]

How can I get around these problems in Matlab? Is there a predefined function in doing these tasks?

My code for plotting the shapes:

```
A =

    -4    -4     4     4    -4
    -2     2     2    -2    -2
plot(A(1,:),A(2,:),'blue')
```

Comment: I think I see the issue, can you post the code to plot the images?

Comment: Still updating my answer with your second problem since you updated it

Comment: Okay my answer should be correct now as long as you don't keep editing the question XD Please accept or let me know if there's anything wrong or needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regarding your 1st problem:**

Essentially you want to do a translation of A to it's centroid before you do the rotation. This is because the rotation assumes that you're rotating about the origin. Therefore you need to "centre" it about the point you plan to rotate it about before you rotate it. Then you need to **translate it back** after you finish the rotation. Refer to [this reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128161100/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69806.html) for details.

```
% Define A
A = [-2,-2,6,6,-2; -2,2,2,-2,-2; 1 1 1 1 1];

% Define Translation Matrix
trans = @(x,y,z) repmat([x; y; z],[1 5]);

% Define Rotation Matrix
se2 = @(x, y, theta) [
    cosd(theta), -sind(theta), x;
    sind(theta), cosd(theta), y;
    0,        0,           1];

% Calculate Rotated Rect
B = se2(0,0,45) * (A - trans(2,0,0) ) + trans(2,0,0);

% Plot Rectangles
figure; plot(A(1,:),A(2,:),'b')
hold on;
plot(B(1,:),B(2,:),'r')
hold off;
axis equal
```

The function `trans` will translate it before the rotation.

Result:

```
>> A
A =
    -2    -2     6     6    -2
    -2     2     2    -2    -2
     1     1     1     1     1
>> B
B =
    0.5858   -2.2426    3.4142    6.2426    0.5858
   -4.2426   -1.4142    4.2426    1.4142   -4.2426
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Here is the A/B if rotated at the centre.

[image]

Here is the A/B with the offset.

[image]

**Regarding your 2nd problem:**

Same solution as the first problem except you use the new centroid and -30 deg instead for the parameters of `B`.

Comment: Sorry still updating my solution

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply :)  I think there should be a predefined function in Matlab for doing so or else I should add a se2 matrix to all my functions so the shapes remember their poses

Comment: Are you talking about not having to use 2 functions to attain your transformation? If so, you can always abstract it into 1 function. If you're asking for a built in function, there is [rotx](http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/rotx.html) and [rotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rotate.html) and a bunch of other built in functions, but personally I like writing my own function because depending on the 3D rotation, you can have different euler angle rotations.

Comment: There are many places to find the rotation matrix given euler angles. Here is one, but like I said, I prefer to write my own. Plus you typically store a translation as a 4/5th variable in the rotation matrix, which you're not doing here. You'd be overcomplicating a 2D case :P
http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846

Comment: Plus if you're only using the 2D case, you can simplify your rotation/translation matrix to a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Anyways please kindly accept my answer, or let me know if there's anything I need to fix!